# Kendo UI Window not centering correctly after upgrade to 2017 R2

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-window

Is anyone have this problem ?
and also the close icon at the right title is not in the middle of the circle when hover the icon.

I think this have relation with the fix for the kendo dialog

Comment: I have a position problem only with I.E.

Comment: @GiovanniRomio also in firefox :(